# how to convert a mongodb date field that is isodate to local date

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a aggregation pipeline like:

```
db.Collection.aggregate([{
              $project:{
                    Name:1,
                    ModDate: new Date("$history.ModDate")
               }}])
```

I tought that Date would convert it to local time but I get the default value of: `1970-01-01 00:00:00.000Z`

Even doh the value of the ModDate is something like:

```
2015-10-18 06:50:19.000Z
```

And `ModDate` on the history subdocument is a `date` field

Is there a way to convert the isodate to the server local date?

Comment: You can try `{
              $project:{
                    Name:1,
                    ModDate: { "date": "$history.ModDate", "timezone": "Europe/Amsterdam" }
               }}` in 3.6

Comment: Can you show the document sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
ModDate: Date("$history.ModDate")
```

(i.e. without the new operator)